# Error running python scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

When running scrapy basic programs, which have a known surety of working on others systems. I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.18.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 167, in <module>
    execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.18.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.18.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 56, in get_project_settings
    settings_module = __import__(settings_module_path, {}, {}, [''])
  File "scrapy_sample.py", line 14
    next_page = 
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also get tons of other errors like. Full list is attached in the code

Comment: You need to post the *full* traceback, that error message is incomplete, just two lines from the complete message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. Include the *whole* traceback, then use the `{}` button on the toolbar (with the traceback selected) to format it correctly.

Comment: My mistake, sorry for the inconvenience. I was not clear what method would be the best. I have changed it. I had downloaded from here. https://github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples, however this basic program also seems not working. :(

Comment: And what is *in* `scrapy_sample.py`? I don't see that file in the repository you linked to.

Comment: I repaired the traceback as best I could; the exact location of the `^` doesn't really matter here. You probably have forgotten to close a parenthesis on the previous line. Without seeing `scrapy_sample.py` this is however only something we can guess at.

Comment: I downloaded the crawler spider example from  github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples, copied in the `items.csv` file and overwrote the two files that were different (`craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test2.py` and `craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\items.py`) and it ran without error. 

Please post your spider code and items.py file so we can assess if there are any differences that are causing the issue.

Comment: Some additional questions: what version of Windows is this running under and is a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory structure must look like this:

```
crawler/
  __init__.py
  items.py
  settings.py
  spiders/
    __init__.py
    craiglist_Sample.py
scrapy.cfg
```

Then call the scrapy command from the same level as the `crawler` directory.

If you already do that, are you sure the `crawler/spiders/craiglist_Sample.py` file exists?

---

Update 2013-10-02: As the link states, there is a SyntaxError in your `scrapy_sample.py` file on line 14. Please fix it.

Comment: It is there, exactly as described. Most important is that the downloaded programs also do not work. I have downloaded from here. https://github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples

Comment: The traceback strongly suggests Python 2.7 is used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, of course. stupid me :/ Answer updated again.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check if you have installed pywin32 as suggested on:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Take care to install the version corresponding to your OS's bitsize, and your python's bitsize --> x64 OS, but x32 Python means you must install x32 pywin32

I received the same errors, but after installing pywin32, it's worked out.

Errors related to Twisted, and Deferred should also be similarly solved